# Unable to deploy a rails application using eb cli

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails, ruby, elastic-beanstalk

I recently updated my environments configuration to :64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.4.6 running Ruby 2.2 (Passenger Standalone). After deploying my application using eb deploy i now get an error in my var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log that states:

```
[2016-01-07T01:45:48.109Z] INFO  [2602]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"(TRUNCATED)...e ']'\n+
 bundle install\nDon't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed,
 and\ninstalling your bundle as root will break this application for all 
non-root\nusers on this machine.\n
Your Ruby version is 2.2.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2. \n
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed.
For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB 
CLI","returncode":18,"events":[]}],"truncated":"true"}
[2016-01-07T01:45:48.110Z] ERROR [2602]  : exit (SystemExit)
at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.7/bin/command-processor:50:in `exit'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.7/bin/command-processor:50:in `<top (required)>'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/command-processor:23:in `load'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/command-processor:23:in `<main>'
```

The activity log doesn't give me anything more:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.2.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2
```

I've updated my Gemfile to ensure it is using 2.2.3 and checked my application for any other references to 2.2.2. I've checked my git commits and dowloaded the application zip file and they all state ruby as 2.2.3.

Every time i deploy the application i get the same error... even when I delete the contents of my gemfile entirely. If I go into /var/app/ondeck and check the gemfile there i can see that it is for some reason listed as 2.2.2 but editing that file does nothing.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this? I just want the application to work I'm not concerned over what ruby version it uses.

Answer (score -1):

Have you rerun `bundler install`? You have likely not had it updated in `Gemfile.lock`.